# Problem with API Post Method Data Insert in Asp.Net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, postman

This is my API in `Controller.cs` page

```
public IHttpActionResult AddData(List<Mobile_Book_Order> obj_add_data)
{
    var response= this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created);
    string json;
            
    ALFDB_13Entities1 db = new ALFDB_13Entities1();
    json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj_add_data);

    for (int i = 0; i < obj_add_data.Count; i++)
    {
        db.Mobile_Book_Order.Add(obj_add_data[i]);
    }
           
    db.SaveChanges();

    response.Content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            
    return ResponseMessage(response);
}
```

This is my Postman request data:

```json
{
    "data":
        [
            { 
              "challenId": "0124555",
              "userId": "enam01",
              "bookOrderDate": "2022-10-17-17:00:15.667423",
              "bookAcCode": "A1BVB/2013",
              "bookName": "Vasa Binnas Uchhotor Bangla Bayakaron & Rochonariti",
              "bookQuantity": "6",
              "bookInitialPrice": 298,
              "bookTotalPrice": 1788,
              "orderCertifyedBy": "you",
              "orderConfirmBy": "me"
            },
            {
              "challenId": "0124555",
              "userId": "enam01",
              "bookOrderDate": "2022-10-17 17:00:15.677775",
              "bookAcCode": "A1DQS/2014",
              "bookName": "Due Part Question Suggestion (Science)",
              "bookQuantity": "8",
              "bookInitialPrice": 51,
              "bookTotalPrice": 408,
              "orderCertifyedBy": "you",
              "orderConfirmBy": "me"
            }
        ]
}
```

When I try to insert data I get an error

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Please help

Comment: On which line do you get this error?

Comment: in "obj_add_data" show null. so when go to for loop show this error

Comment: And what does your model class `Mobile_Book_Order` look like?

Comment: is this a POST request?

Comment: Your postman request json has a top level node of "data" followed by elements, whereas your parameter is strictly just a list of elements. This may not work depending on your serialisation strategy.

Comment: how can i solved this?

Comment: Just take a look at [C# Coding Conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/coding-style/coding-conventions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keet your API same, then you should change your `JSON` like this:

```
[
    { 
        "challenId": "0124555",
        "userId": "enam01",
        "bookOrderDate": "2022-10-17-17:00:15.667423",
        "bookAcCode": "A1BVB/2013",
        "bookName": "Vasa Binnas Uchhotor Bangla Bayakaron & Rochonariti",
        "bookQuantity": "6",
        "bookInitialPrice": 298,
        "bookTotalPrice": 1788,
        "orderCertifyedBy": "you",
        "orderConfirmBy": "me"
    },
    {
        "challenId": "0124555",
        "userId": "enam01",
        "bookOrderDate": "2022-10-17 17:00:15.677775",
        "bookAcCode": "A1DQS/2014",
        "bookName": "Due Part Question Suggestion (Science)",
        "bookQuantity": "8",
        "bookInitialPrice": 51,
        "bookTotalPrice": 408,
        "orderCertifyedBy": "you",
        "orderConfirmBy": "me"
    }
]
```

If you want to keep your JSON same then you should change your model like this:

```
public class Mobile_Book_Order
{
    public string challenId { get; set; }
    public string userId { get; set; }
    public string bookOrderDate { get; set; }
    public string bookAcCode { get; set; }
    public string bookName { get; set; }
    public string bookQuantity { get; set; }
    public int bookInitialPrice { get; set; }
    public int bookTotalPrice { get; set; }
    public string orderCertifyedBy { get; set; }
    public string orderConfirmBy { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public List<Mobile_Book_Order> data { get; set; }
}

public IHttpActionResult AddData(Root obj_add_data)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Just take a look at [What is voting up?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up)